# Why does Mixpanel (a tracking service) save .plist files to my Mac?

Tags: privacy, analytics, tracking

While cleaning up some old programs today, I ran across some odd .plist files which appear to be created by MixPanel. Why are they saving these to my computer, when in a typical web application architecture, trackable user events are sent directly to the end destination (in this case, MixPanel's API) for analysis?

[image: Screenshot of .plist files saved by MixPanel]

Edit: The three filenames end in “events”, “people”, and “properties”, respectively. There are attributes such as “distinctID”, “peopleUnidentifiedQueue”, and others within these files. They don’t seem innocuous.

Comment: Do you know how long they've been there? What browser(s) have you used? On recent releases of Safari, I think any web assets would be sandboxed in a Safari-only area. My guess is that this is from a native Mac app, again probably prior to protections being added to macOS for full disk access.

Comment: @pseudon I appreciate the response. All three files were created Feburary 6, 2018. I only use Chrome. I do believe you are correct regarding it being a native Mac app. Stay tuned, I think I may have found the culprit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Case Closed

I've successfully identified the source of these files. It was indeed a native Mac app. (I am not aware of any method in which a web application can write to your filesystem beyond an explicit download prompt.)

The culprit app turned out to be Etcher.io AKA [BalenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/).

### How I Found the Culprit

I discovered this by opening each of my Mac apps individually, hoping that one of them would attempt to update these files, given that they are associated with a user behavior tracking service. I fully opened each, played around a bit with each, and then fully quit each. I made sure to wait a few minutes before opening an application after closing another.

Eventually, I saw the .plist files be updated when I opened BalenaEtcher. The files were actually completely recreated upon opening the app, so the "Created" and "Modified" timestamps matched exactly when I opened it.

Additionally, I stumbled upon [this GitHub issue for the actual Etcher.io project](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/issues/1772), which reaffirmed my belief they were using MixPanel. There are other discussions online regarding this background tracking, just search for "balenaetcher mixpanel".